# C programming - copy file to an other

Tags: c, file, fopen, fwrite, fread

I implemented the following function

```
int copy_files(char *source, char *destination)
{
    FILE *in_fd, *out_fd;

    char *buf;
    char buffer[512];

    time_t t;
    struct tm *td;

    long file_size;
    int result;
    int value;

    int status =  STATUS_ERROR;

    /* Open file for both reading and writing */
    in_fd = fopen(source, "w+");    //
    if(in_fd == NULL)
    {
       fputs ("File error",stderr);
       exit (1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("writing in file...\n");

        strcpy(buffer, "Test writing in USB Key File \n");
        fprintf(in_fd, buffer); 
        printf("%s\n",buffer);
        t = time(NULL);
        td = gmtime((const time_t *)&t);
        sprintf(buffer, "Date %02d/%02d/%02d Time %02d:%02d:%02d\n", 
        td->tm_mday, td->tm_mon + 1, td->tm_year + 1900,
        td->tm_hour, td->tm_min, td->tm_sec);
        fprintf(in_fd, buffer);
        printf("%s\n",buffer);
        printf("Writing OK\n");
    }

    out_fd = fopen(destination,"w+");
    if(out_fd == NULL)
    {
        fputs ("File error",stderr);
        exit (1);
    }   
    else
    {   
        // obtain file size:
        fseek (in_fd , 0 , SEEK_END);
        file_size = ftell (in_fd);
        rewind (in_fd);

        // allocate memory to contain the whole file:
        buf = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*file_size);  

        while (!feof(in_fd)) 
        {
            /* Read  data */
            fread(buf, 1, (sizeof buf), in_fd);
            printf("%s", buf);
        }

        /* Write  data */
        fwrite(buf, 1, (sizeof buf), out_fd);
    } 
    fclose(in_fd);
    fclose(out_fd);
    return STATUS_OK;
}
```

Through this function, I would like to create a file, fill it with two lines and copy this entire contain to an other file.

Howerver I not understand why :

1. The destination file is not created contrary to the source one.
2. printf diplay :

   writing in file...
   Test writing in USB Key File 
   Date 01/01/1970 Time 00:45:46
   Writing OK
   Testh��v wrih��vtingh��v in h��vUSB h��vKey h��vFileh��v 
   Dah��vte 0h��v1/01h��v/197h��v0 Tih��vme 0h��v0:45h��v:46
   h��v:46

How to resolve the issues ?

EDIT :

About the first question I do not understand why the following code :

```
strcat(temp_dest, direntp->d_name);
printf("after strcat temp_dest=%s\n", temp_dest);         
strcat(temp_src, direntp->d_name);
printf("after strcat temp_src=%s\n", temp_src); 
printf("destination:%s\n",temp_dest);
copy_files(temp_src,temp_dest);
```

returns :

```
after strcat temp_dest=/tmp/usb/test10
after strcat temp_src=/media/sda1/test10
destination:10
```

Why 10 ? :/

Comment: Suggestion: in `if(out_fd == NULL)`, close `in_fd` before `exit()`.

Comment: Hint: `while (!feof(in_fd))` is bad. also, you're reading in a loop and writing only once.

Comment: @SnP, Could you please add more code for the `EDIT` ? As what does `direntp` read, including calls to `opendir/readdir` ? expected output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correction in your `fread()`.

Since you already know the `filesize`.
No need to loop, one call to `fread` reading `file_size` bytes is sufficient.

```
else                                                                        
{                                                                           
    // obtain file size:                                                    
    fseek (in_fd , 0 , SEEK_END);                                           
    file_size = ftell (in_fd);                                              
    rewind (in_fd);                                                         

    // allocate memory to contain the whole file:                           
    buf = malloc (file_size);                                               

    /* Read file_size no of bytes */                                                        
    fread(buf, 1, file_size, in_fd);                                      
    buf[file_size -1] = 0;                                                  
    printf("File content after Reading :[%s]", buf);                        

    /* Write  data */                                                       
    fwrite(buf, 1, file_size, out_fd);                                      
}
```

Other Correction in your code.
You are missing `%s` (second argument) in `fprintf`.

```
...
else                                                  
{                                                                           
    printf("writing in file...\n");                                         

    strcpy(buffer, "Test writing in USB Key File \n");                      
    fprintf(in_fd, "%s", buffer); 
    ...                                 

    fprintf(in_fd, "%s", buffer);                                      
    printf("Writing OK\n");     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are checking the file size before reading, you don't need to loop and check for EOF.

The real problem here is just that you read and write using `sizeof(buf)`, but `buf` is just a pointer, so its size is 4 bytes (or 8). What you need to use is `sizeof(char)*file_size`, which is the real size of your buffer.